# hmvc Message: Undefined property: CI::$Templates code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

Hi am watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS0GeknUkds for setting up my hmvc templates. i am already trying to call other modules but i got the error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$Templates

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 59
```

i have this templates folder with a controller file Templates.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Templates extends MY_Controller{

    public function views($data = NULL){

        $this->load->view('templates/one_view');
    }
}

?>
```

this perfectly works if i directly called it. but the problem is on my login module.(http://localhost/ci_hmvc/index.php/login/index) i get the error,

```
Message: Undefined property: CI::$Templates

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 59
```

and

```
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function views() on null

Filename: controllers/Login.php

Line Number: 10
```

my controller is,

Login.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller{


    public function index(){

        $data['content_view'] = 'login/login_view';
        $this->Templates->views($data);

    }
}

?>
```

how can i resolve this? is there is a problem with the hmvc setting ? or what?

p.s

i extended it to MY_Controllers because i have this file,

MY_Controller.php on my core folder..

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    function __contsruct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('Templates');
    }

}

?>
```

thanks

Comment: $this->Templates->views($data);
 seriously ??  what are you trying to do with this code ??

Comment: i just tried to copy the codes on the video. i know how templating works for the normal mvc code igniter. but i am trying to learn hmvc so i watched and try to copy the codes on this video.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS0GeknUkds ]

Comment: Try some thing like  `$this->load->module('module/controller/function');` or `Modules::run('module/controller/function');`

Comment: i need to do is to put $data into  `public function views($data = NULL){`

Comment: and i cant do that using the way you told me

Comment: Yes you can. `$this->load->views('view', $data);` works exactly the same as it would without HMVC as long as your views folder resides in the module. I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish any other way. @wolfgang1983 suggestion is almost as strange as the method in which you're trying to accomplish this. When loading a module, load the module. Make calls to controllers and methods after the load. e.g. `$this->load->module('my_calendar_module', 'calendar');` I set the 2nd parameter to shorten the call so you can do this. `$this->calendar->somemethod();`

Answer (score 0):

In My_Controller change

```
function __contsruct
```

to

```
function __construct()
```

Comment: yes. some one already told me that. but i still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you a set or adding module path?
If not yet. You can set your application/config/config.php like this

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

And your login.php change

```
public function index(){

        $data['content_view'] = 'login/login_view';
        $this->Templates->views($data);

    }
```

To

```
public function index(){

        $data['content_view'] = 'login/login_view';
        $this->templates->views($data);

    }
```